# How to write each letter into a file from a input file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def main():
    filename = input('Enter filename: ')
    f = read(filename)
    out_file = input('Enter file: ')
    of = out(out_file)
```

//I think the code is quite inefficient, can I make it more efficient?

```
for line in f:
   for words in line.split():
      for letter in words:

          if (words.isalpha()): 
             of.write(letter.lower())
    of.write('\n')
```

Comment: what are you trying to do? what's exactly is the problem here?

Comment: @avi I just want to make the code more efficient, 3 loops seems quite unnecessary, but I don't know how to do that. The codes works like this as well. read is a module used to read the file and out is a module that creates the output file.

Answer (score 2):

This will print each letter of the file

```
with open('foo.txt', 'r+') as f:
    a = [l for line in f for l in line if l.isalpha()]
    with open('out_file.txt', 'w') as w:
        for i in a:
            w.write(i.lower())
```

Comment: Well, it'll create a list of them, but it won't print them, or save them to a file. FWIW, I gather from the the first code block in the question that Vamosnadal123 isn't exactly clear on Python syntax...

Comment: @PM2Ring i think updated code will do what you are asking for.

Comment: Ok. But I'm pretty sure that the OP wants the output in a different file, not appended to the input file.

Comment: I know how to save it into a file, but is there no way just to have one loop?

Comment: Also I cannot write the lines the exact way it was read in. For example, if the read in file was a b (new line) b a, this writes abba into the new file.

Comment: @PM2Ring Yeah, I'm kinda new to python.

Comment: I don't think so that we can read characters in just a single loop as file is iterated over lines,

Comment: @Vamosnadal123 : It writes `abba` into the new file because you said you _just_ want to copy the letters, so that's what Vishnu's program is doing - it isn't copying anything but letters (converted to lower case). In particular, it isn't copying the newline char `\n` at the end of each input line. You need to be more precise in your question statement!

Comment: @VishnuUpadhyay : We can read chars one a a time using `f.read(1)` but it's a bit inefficient, so generally avoided. It _would_ be **very** inefficient, but fortunately the OS buffers the file.

Comment: @VishnuUpadhyay : I wasn't suggesting to read chars one at a time, just saying it's possible. Similarly, you shouldn't write chars one at a time, which is what the code in the question is doing. I'd contribute an answer myself, but it's getting late & I have to go.

Answer (score 0):

Using @vishnu-upadhyay answer and considering  @vamosnadal123 comment:

```
out = open('out_file.txt', 'w')
_ = [w for line in open('foo.txt', 'r') for w in line if w.isalpha() or w=='\n']
out.close()
```

EDIT:
if you also want to keep all space you could write this, that is inded nicer:

```
out = open('out_file.txt', 'w')
_ = [w for line in open('foo.txt', 'r') for w in line if w.isalpha() or w.isspace()]
out.close()
```

EDIT2 sorry for intensive editing, I think this is a nicer solution:

```
out = open('out_file.txt', 'w')
_ = [''.join([w for w in line if w.isalpha()]) + '\n' for line in open('foo.txt', 'r')]
out.close()
```